# Finding total surface area of frustum, trouble with forumulas

Tags: python, python-3.x, geometry

I'm writing a program for a class to find the volume and surface area of a frustum when given both the radius values and the height as input from the user. I think I am on the right track, but I am not confident in how I've put the formula into python. The formula given to use to find the surface area is:
 [image: Formula]

Here is my code:

```
import math
def main():
    radius1Length = float(input("Please enter the first radius:"))
    radius2Length = float(input("Please enter the second radius:"))
    heightNum = float(input("Please enter the height:"))
    volumeTotal = volume(radius1Length,radius2Length,heightNum)
    sAreaTotal = surfaceArea(radius1Length,radius2Length,heightNum)
    print("The radius values used were:", radius1Length, "and", radius2Length)
    print("The height used was:", heightNum)
    print("The volume is:", volumeTotal)
    print("The surace area is:", sAreaTotal)

## Compute the volume of a frustum
# @pram radius1 a float giving the length of the first radius value
# @pram radius2 a float giving the length of the second radius value
# @pram height a float giving the height value
# @return the volume of the frustum as a float
def volume(radius1,radius2,height):
    volumeValue = (1/3) * math.pi * height * (radius1**2 + radius2**2 + (radius1 * radius2))
    return volumeValue
## Compute the surface area of a frustum
# @pram radius1 a float giving the length of the first radius value
# @pram radius2 a float giving the length of the second radius value
# @pram height a flot givign the height value
# @raturn the surface area of the frustum as a float
def surfaceArea(radius1,radius2,height):
    sArea = math.pi * ((radius1 + radius2) * math.sqrt( height**2 + ((radius2 - radius1)**2) + (math.pi * (radius1**2))))
    return sArea

main()
```

If anybody can even confirm that this is the correct way to write out that formula in python it would be much appreciated

Comment: Looks like that last \pi R^2 is in the \sqrt in your python code, but not in the given formula.  Rearrange your parens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with the brackets. You wrote:

```
sArea = pi * ((r1+r2) * sqrt(h**2 + ((r2-r1)**2) + (pi * (r1**2))))
```

Which corresponds to:

[image: wrong equation]

as you notice, the `pi * (r1 ** 2)` is put under the square root as well, which is not correct.

You can rewrite it to:

```
from math import pi, sqrt

def surfaceArea(r1, r2, h):
    return pi * (r1 + r2) * sqrt((r2-r1)**2 + h*h) + pi * r1 * r1
```

or more verbose:

```
from math import pi, sqrt

def surfaceArea(radius1, radius2, h):
    return pi * (radius1 + radius2) * sqrt((radius2-radius1)**2 + height**2) + pi * (radius1**2)
```

But actually writing `x * x` is typically more efficient (as well as numerically correct, than writing `x ** 2`).

**EDIT**:

the formula you present is however incorrect. The formula is:

[image: correct equation]

We can implement this as:

```
from math import pi, sqrt

def surfaceArea(r1, r2, h):
    return pi * ((r1 + r2) * sqrt((r2-r1)**2 + h*h) + r1*r1 + r2*r2)
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even realized how much basic math I had forgotten or that I overlook until I started learning python. I know the formula is incorrect, that is just what was given for us to use so I'm not sure why we were given a wrong one

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't the surface area of a frustum be the following?

```
pi * (radius1 + radius2) * sqrt((radius2-radius1)**2 + height**2)
+ pi * (radius1**2)
+ pi * (radius2**2)
```

You missed `pi * (radius2**2)` in addition to the wrong placement of the brackets?